# Where is payment status 'Hold' in ipn simulator

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn

My paypal ipn is working fine the status is getting updated but if the payment status chances to hold in case of a dispute then the payment status in database updates to null or empty, so I assume paypal returns the status as empty or null in case of hold due to a dispute.

I was trying to test the payment status hold in the sandbox to confirm this but I didn't find any option to simulate the hold status. Where is the status hold supposed to be in the ipn simulator ?

[Check the image it has every other status except the "hold" status.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLfa8.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a payment hold the `payment_status` will be Pending.

When a payment is Pending, there will be a `pending_reason` set.